# jedi-vim python3 autocompletion working

Tags: vim, python-3.x, matplotlib, scipy

I am using vim for python3 coding with davidhalter's jedi-vim plugin for autocomplete. I have Numpy, SciPy and matplotlib setup. For Numpy, autocomplete suggesting correctly. However, it's not working with SciPy and matplotlib, for example

```
import numpy as np
np.[abs absolute add add_docstring .... long list suggested here]

import scipy as sci
sci.[no list but "Omni completion (^O^N^P) Pattern not found" in status area]
```

I have it setup on two of my current working machine. OSX 10.8 and Fedora 18. jedi-vim is installed using Vundle. All three libraries are installed using pip3 on OSX and yum from default repository on fedora 18. Function in all library can be called in run-time successfully. Am I missing something here?

Comment: jedi-vim's issue tracker is [that way](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim/issues?state=closed).

Comment: Does this work? `python -c "import jedi; print jedi.Script('import scipy; scipy.').completions()"` For me scipy works. Ensure that you installed scipy with the right python version (the one that VIM uses).